# Error in arulesSequences in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to do a sequential pattern analysis using aruleSequences in R.

My data set has 626,047 rows after removing all kinds of duplicates. It has 3 columns. I unfortunately cant put the dataset out here. I have created sample data in a google sheet to give an idea of how the data looks like. it is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yD1WSZA9SectTFIROcHLPGYaB4fLhoDRPstHT_8nGlk/edit?usp=sharing). The data is named as df_sq

It has 3 columns:

1. Numeric_id of class numeric . This is a user_id
2. Product - of class factor.
3. Time - of class integer

I have been able to convert the data in 'transaction' format according to the package. But on running cSpade, i get the following error:

```
Error in makebin(data, file) : 'eid' invalid (strict order)
```

Now, i know from reading other questions on Stackoverflow, that this means that i have to sort my data. 
So i went back and sorted my orignal data by numeric_id and time. Vice versa as well. And re coverted data to 'transaction' format and re ran cSpade.

I am still getting the same error.

Has any one worked with this package before?

Here is the code i had used:

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(arulesSequences)
library(sqldf)

df_sq = read.csv("service_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Changing class of timestamp column and coercing product name to factor

df_sq$time1 = as.integer(as.numeric(df_sq$time1))
df_sq$service_name = as.factor(df_sq$service_name)

#Clearing duplicates

df_sq = sqldf("select distinct numeric_id, service_name, time1 
               from df_sq")

#Ordering the dataset on numeric id and time

df_sq = df_sq3[order(df_sq3$numeric_id, df_sq3$time1),] 
df_sq = df_sq3[order(df_sq3$time1),]
df_sq = df_sq3[order(df_sq3$sequenceID),]

#Coverting to transactional format per the package

sq_data = data.frame(item=df_sq3$service_name)
sq_tran = as(sq_data, "transactions")
transactionInfo(sq_tran)$sequenceID = df_sq3$numeric_id
transactionInfo(sq_tran)$eventID = df_sq3$time1

summary(sq_tran)

#Running cSpade

s1 = cspade(sq_tran, parameter = list(support = 0.1), control = list(verbose 
= TRUE),tmpdir = tempdir())

summary(s1)
```

Comment: @jogo Sorry for that. Edited

Comment: It's unlikely that you will help with the information provided. Please add something like the result of `dput(sq_tran)` to your post. `sq_tran` must reproduce your error message. You can also use artificial dummy data in sq_tran. Important thing is that it yields the error.